# Почему push notification не замещает предыдущий?

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Я имплементировал `push notification` с загрузкой.

И по идее как только загрузка заканчивается срздается новый нотификейшн без загрузки который замещает старый(то есть в итоге на экране мы всегда видим только один `notification`)

Вот код

```
public void Progress_notif(Context context) {

    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_autorenew_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int incr;
                    for (incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr += 10) {
                        mBuilder.setProgress(100, incr, false);
                        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "sleep failure");
                        }
                    }
                    mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete").setProgress(0, 0, false);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(10, mBuilder.build());
                }
            }
    ).start();
}
```

Все работает отлично, только когда загрузка заканчивается то `notification` не замещается, а просто создается новый `notification` и появляется снизу...

Как сделать так, чтоб старый `notification` исчезал и замещался новым?

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас первый `notify` параметр разный:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
...
mNotificationManager.notify(10, mBuilder.build());
```

Т.е. это разные нотификации. RTFM [notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

> id    int: An identifier for this notification unique within your application.